# I want to visualize the following data frame in a single visualization

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

The dataframe looks like this

[image: Dataframe]

I wanted to visualize this in a single chart, like a barplot.
This needs to be done in python 3.
I have tried heat map but it doesn't look good enough.
Any other suggestions about visualizations which may look cooler are are also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`seaborn.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html)

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set(style="whitegrid")

df = pd.DataFrame({"knn": [0.93, 0.91, 0.91],
                   "naive": [0.83, 0.83, 0.85],
                   "decis": [0.96, 0.96, 0.96],
                   "random": [0.96, 0.96, 0.96],
                   "svm": [0.95, 0.95, 0.96]},
                   index=["accuracy", "jacard", "f1"])

df = df.stack().reset_index()
df.columns = ['metrics', 'algo', 'val']
sns.barplot(x='metrics', y='val',hue='algo', data=df)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0)
plt.show()
```

and you get:

[image]